# Show that $ e^x \le 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3} $ when $ 0 \le x \le 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Here's my approach. 
By the definition,

$ e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{n!} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+... $

Then

$e^x -1 -x -\frac{x^2}{2!}=\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}... \le \frac{x^3}{2^2}+\frac{x^4}{2^3}...$

Since $0 \le x \le 1 $, it is obvious that $x^k \le x^3 $ for $ k \ge 3 \in N $. Therefore,

$\frac{x^3}{2^2}+\frac{x^4}{2^3}+\frac{x^5}{2^4}...\le \frac{x^3}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{2^3}+\frac{x^3}{2^4}... $

Therfore,

$e^x -1 -x-\frac{x^2}{2!}=\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}... \le \frac{x^3}{2^2}+\frac{x^3}{2^3}+\frac{x^3}{2^4}...=\frac{\frac{x^3}{2^2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\frac{x^3}{2^2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{x^3}{2}  $

Finally,

$e^x -1 -x - \frac{x^2}{2} \le \frac{x^3}{2} $, therefore $e^x\le 1 + x+ x^2 + \frac{x^3}{2} $

But the problem is I can't prove that $ e^x \le 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3} $ because what I showed is $e^x\le 1 + x+ x^2 + \frac{x^3}{2} $.

Also, I might not be able to use infinite series sum formula and my TA told me that I have to approach in a different way probably using $ e^x= \lim_{n->\infty} (1+  \frac{x}{n})^n$, but I have no idea where to start. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So where are you in the calculus course? You can use the Lagrange expression for the remainder term, but I'm not sure if this will be allowed.

Comment: This is real analysis question. Basically, I can't use integration

Comment: please see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let us try without derivation. As $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n/n!,$ we need to prove
$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} x^n/n! \leq x^3/3,$$
or
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k+3)!} \leq \frac{1}{3},$$
or
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k+3)!} \leq \frac{1}{6}.$$
for $0\leq x\leq 1$.
It is easy to see that for $s\geq 4$
$$\frac{1}{s!}\leq \frac{1}{2*(s-1)*s} = \frac{1}{2(s-1)}-\frac{1}{2s},$$
so 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{(k+3)!} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+3)!} \leq \sum_{l=3}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{2l}-\frac{1}{2l+2} \right ) = \frac{1}{6}, $$
q.e.d.

Comment: Why is it (k+3)! ? Isn't it (k+2)!

Comment: Yes, of course I need to correct it, thank you

Comment: If it's changed to (k+2)! , it doesn't work, does it?

Comment: I just a little bit sharpened my estimate, so now it works. Thank you for quick eye!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that $e^x=\partial^3_x e^x \leq \partial^3_x ( 1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3})=1+2x$ because the function $e^x$ is convex and $(1+2x)_{|x=1}=3>e$.

Then you will have that, due to $e^0=1=(1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3})_{|x=0}$, then  $e^x<1+x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{x^3}{3}$ for all $0<x \leq 1$.

Comment: Will there be other solution not using differentiation?

Answer (score 0):

$$ e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{∞} \frac{x^k}{(k)!}$$
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$e^{x}-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!} = \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$
$$e^{x}-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!} = \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{8}+\frac{x^2}{40}+\cdots$$
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{8}+\frac{x^2}{40}+\cdots)$$
If $x$ approaches $0$
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}+\cdots)$$
If $x$ approaches $1$
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots)$$
Generally if $0\le x \le 1$ then
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(M)$$
For positive $x$ less than $1$, $M$ is always greater than $\frac{1}{2}$
$$e^{x} = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}\cdot(M)$$
$M \ge \frac{1}{2}$
$$e^{x} < 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3}$$